# Getting value from selected row in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm a novice vb programmer trying to retrieve the value of the selected row in a gridview. Haven't been able to as of yet. I've searched all the forums, none of the answers have worked for me.
Here is the html portion of the code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
                ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="1032px" 
                EnableModelValidation="True">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" onclick ="LinkButton1_Click"
                CommandName="DrillTP" Text='<%#Eval("transit_date")%>'> </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="transit_date" HeaderText="Date"  Visible="false" >

            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            </asp:BoundField>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="day_type" HeaderText="DayType" >

            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="current_route_id" HeaderText="Line" >

            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="bs_lname" HeaderText="Location" >

            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            </asp:BoundField>

        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />

    </asp:GridView>
```

in visual basic, I'm trying to capture the selected date and place that info in a label, but haven't been able to yet. any suggestions? I have this:

```
Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) '(sender As Object, e As DataGridCommandEventArgs)
            Label1.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.DataItem

End Sub
```

clearly, I'm missing something, any help is appreciated. Also, please let me know if I can post this question more effectively.
thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the property Value, and perhaps use the ToString method.

```
GridView1.SelectedRows(0).Value.ToString()
```

Comment: 'selectedrows' is not an option at that point, but 'selectedrow' is. I tried that, but it didn't work